# Entity Framework Exception "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a windows service which listen to a TCP/IP port and save received data in database using Entity Framework. Most of the time it works fine but some time its throwing an exception "The underlying provider failed on open." on save data in database.
Here is my exception details:

```
    Exception: 2/27/2014 10:31 AM:
    The underlying provider failed on Open.
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
     at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
     at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
     at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
    at Service.DemoService.Save(String received, TcpClient client)
```

What is the thing behind this exception and how to resolve it?

Comment: Check your connection string

Comment: My connection string `<add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=TDB;UID=admin123;PWD=123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, when working with Entity Framework you'll need to enable the [multiple active result sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option in your connection string by setting *MultipleActiveResultSets* to *true* as follows.

```
<add name="conn" 
  connectionString="
    Data Source=.\;
    Initial Catalog=TDB;
    UID=admin123;
    PWD=123;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Verify that it solves your problem.

Comment: MultipleActiveResultSets is already set to True in my config but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you SQL Server is running or not. 
Just Open Task Manager and Goto Services, Click on Services button below and check whether SQL Server is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that the account which I was using to connect to SQL server was not added to app pool identity. Once I added the account 'domain\username' to app pool, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Change
integrated security= False ; MultipleActiveResultSets=True
in your connection string , it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but I solved it by Opening Task Manager, Go to Services and checking if my SQL Server is running or not. Your Sql server should be running.

Comment: Hi Gomotso - I think your answer is the same as the one given by user3139697.

Answer (score 0):

I am using all this but this is gives same error then I use this this was fixed my error.

> Max Pool Size=100;

```
<add name="conn" 
 connectionString="
 Data Source=.\;
 Initial Catalog=TDB;
 UID=admin123;
 PWD=123;
 Max Pool Size=100;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```